# AddRecord TableView controller -->MasterTableView Controller --> second (filter) TableView Controller --> DetailView Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, navigationcontroller

I'm new to iOS programing (and programming in general). I'm trying to do an iPhone App based on the Birdsighting example provided by Apple (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html). The difference is that I will create Body Building's workouts (instead of Birdsightings) in an AddWorkout TableView Controller, pass the workout to the Master TableView Controller and from there being able, by selecting a workout's cell, to display a second TableView Controller similar to the Master's one, that shows events of that workout sorted by muscle bands; then, selecting a muscle band cell, pushing a DetailView Controller with all relative parameters of that muscle band's workout (exercise type, weight, series number....). All this is embedded in a navigation controller.

The problem is that I can't pass a new record on the second TableView Controller (MuscleBandViewController) and therefore I can't neither push it to the detailViewController. Any suggestion? I'm stuck for a week 'til now (sorry for my bad English: I'm Italian).
**Here is my DataController.h code:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Workouts;

@interface IFitDataController : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy)NSMutableArray *masterWorkoutsList;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSMutableArray *masterMuscleBandList;

- (NSUInteger)countOfList;
- (NSUInteger)countOfMuscleBandList;
- (Workouts *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex;
- (Workouts *)objectInMasterMuscleBandListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)addWorkoutsWithWorkouts:(Workouts *)thisWorkout;
@end
```

**Here DataController.m:**

```
#import "IFitDataController.h"
#import "Workouts.h"

@interface IFitDataController ()
- (void)initializeDefaultDataList;

@end

@interface IFitDataController ()
- (void)initializeMuscleBandDataList;

@end
@implementation IFitDataController

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList {

    NSMutableArray *workoutsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.masterWorkoutsList = workoutsList;
    Workouts *thisWorkout;
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    thisWorkout = [[Workouts alloc] initWithName:@"Pectorals" exercise:@"Pectoral Machine" series:@"3" nActionsInSerie:@"10" measure:@"Kg"  weight:@"25" date:today comment:@"Add your comment"];
    [self addWorkoutsWithWorkouts:thisWorkout];
}

- (void)setMasterWorkoutsList:(NSMutableArray *)newList {

    if (_masterWorkoutsList != newList) {
        _masterWorkoutsList = [newList mutableCopy];
    }
}

- (void)initializeMuscleBandDataList {

    NSMutableArray *muscleBandList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.masterMuscleBandList = muscleBandList;
    Workouts *thisWorkout;
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    thisWorkout = [[Workouts alloc] initWithName:@"Pectorals" exercise:@"Pectoral Machine" series:@"3" nActionsInSerie:@"10" measure:@"Kg"  weight:@"25" date:today comment:@"Add your comment"];
    [self addWorkoutsWithWorkouts:thisWorkout];
}

- (void)setMasterMuscleBandList:(NSMutableArray *)newMuscleBandList {

    if ((_masterMuscleBandList != newMuscleBandList)) {
        _masterMuscleBandList = [newMuscleBandList mutableCopy];
    }
}


- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self initializeDefaultDataList];
        [self initializeMuscleBandDataList];
        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}



- (NSUInteger)countOfList {

    return [self.masterWorkoutsList count];

}

- (NSUInteger)countOfMuscleBandList {

    return [self.masterMuscleBandList count];
}

- (Workouts *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex {

    return [self.masterWorkoutsList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

- (Workouts *)objectInMasterMuscleBandListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    return [self.masterMuscleBandList objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (void)addWorkoutsWithWorkouts:(Workouts *)thisWorkout {

    [self.masterWorkoutsList addObject:thisWorkout];
    [self.masterMuscleBandList addObject:thisWorkout];
}
@end
```

**Here my AddWorkoutViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define muscleBandComponent 0
#define exercisesComponent 1
@class Workouts;

@interface AddWorkoutViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *exercisePicker;
    IBOutlet UITextView *commentInserted;
    NSArray *_exercisesForPicker;
    NSArray *_muscleBandForPicker;
    NSDictionary *totalExercises;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *muscleBandName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *exerciseName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nSeries;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *measureType;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nActionsInSerie;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *weightPerformed;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *commentInserted;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *exercisePicker;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *muscleBandForPicker;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary *totalExercises;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *exercisesForPicker;


- (IBAction)nSeriesStepper:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)nActionsSerieStepper:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)weightStepper:(id)sender;

- (void) closeKeyboard;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Workouts *workout;
@end
```

**Here my AddWorkoutViewController.m:**

```
#import "AddWorkoutViewController.h"

#import "Workouts.h"

#import "IFitDataController.h"

@interface AddWorkoutViewController ()

@end


@implementation AddWorkoutViewController
@synthesize exercisePicker;
@synthesize totalExercises;
@synthesize exercisesForPicker;
@synthesize muscleBandForPicker;


@synthesize nSeries;
@synthesize nActionsInSerie;
@synthesize weightPerformed;
@synthesize commentInserted;


- (IBAction)nSeriesStepper:(id)sender {

    self.nSeries.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(UIStepper *)sender value]] intValue]];

}
- (IBAction)nActionsSerieStepper:(id)sender {

    self.nActionsInSerie.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(UIStepper *)sender value]] intValue]];
}
- (IBAction)weightStepper:(id)sender {

    self.weightPerformed.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(UIStepper *)sender value]] intValue]];
}


- (IBAction) go:(id)sender
{

    [self closeKeyboard];
    }


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]) {
        if ([self.exerciseName.text length] || [self.muscleBandName.text length]) {
            Workouts *thisWorkout;

            NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
            thisWorkout = [[Workouts alloc] initWithName:self.muscleBandName.text exercise:self.exerciseName.text series:self.nSeries.text nActionsInSerie:self.nActionsInSerie.text measure:self.measureType.text  weight:self.weightPerformed.text date:today comment:self.commentInserted.text];
            self.workout = thisWorkout;
        }
    }
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ((textField == self.exerciseName) || (textField == self.muscleBandName)) {

        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    }

    return YES;
}

- (void) closeKeyboard
{
    if([commentInserted isFirstResponder])
    {
        [commentInserted resignFirstResponder];
    }

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"muscleBands" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    self.totalExercises = dictionary;


    NSArray *components = [self.totalExercises allKeys];
    NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    self.muscleBandForPicker = sorted;

    NSString *selectedMuscleBand = [self.muscleBandForPicker objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [totalExercises objectForKey:selectedMuscleBand];
    self.exercisesForPicker = array;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    if (component == muscleBandComponent) 
        return [self.muscleBandForPicker count];


    return [self.exercisesForPicker count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    if (component == muscleBandComponent) 

       return [self.muscleBandForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
     return [self.exercisesForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    if (component == muscleBandComponent) {

        NSString *selectedMuscleBand = [self.muscleBandForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
        NSArray *array = [totalExercises objectForKey:selectedMuscleBand];
        self.exercisesForPicker = array;
        [exercisePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:exercisesComponent animated:YES];
        [exercisePicker reloadComponent:exercisesComponent];

        self.muscleBandName.text = [muscleBandForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
        return;
        }
    self.exerciseName.text = [exercisesForPicker objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

**Here my MasterViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class IFitDataController;
@class Workouts;

@interface IFitMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IFitDataController *dataController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IFitDataController *muscleBandDataController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Workouts *thisWorkout;

- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
- (IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end
```

**Here MasterViewController.m:**:

```
#import "IFitMasterViewController.h"

#import "IFitDetailViewController.h"

#import "IFitDataController.h"

#import "Workouts.h"

#import "AddWorkoutViewController.h"

#import "IFitMuscleBandViewController.h"

@implementation IFitMasterViewController

- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]) {
        AddWorkoutViewController *addController = [segue sourceViewController];
        if (addController.workout) {
            [self.dataController addWorkoutsWithWorkouts:addController.workout];
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput"]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.dataController = [[IFitDataController alloc]init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataController countOfList];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WorkoutCell";

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Workouts *workoutAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel]setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)workoutAtIndex.date]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:workoutAtIndex.comment];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowMuscleBandList"]) {
         IFitMasterViewController *muscleBandViewController = [segue destinationViewController];



        muscleBandViewController.thisWorkout = [self.muscleBandDataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];            

    }
}

@end
```

**Here MuscleBandViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class IFitDataController;

@interface IFitMuscleBandViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) Workouts *thisWorkout;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IFitDataController *dataController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IFitDataController *muscleBandDataController;

@end
```

**Here MuscleBandViewController.m:**

```
#import "IFitMasterViewController.h"

#import "IFitDetailViewController.h"

#import "IFitDataController.h"

#import "Workouts.h"

#import "AddWorkoutViewController.h"

#import "IFitMuscleBandViewController.h"

@class IFitDataController;

@implementation IFitMuscleBandViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.muscleBandDataController = [[IFitDataController alloc]init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.muscleBandDataController countOfMuscleBandList];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MuscleBandCell";

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Workouts *workoutAtIndex = [self.muscleBandDataController objectInMasterMuscleBandListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel]setText:workoutAtIndex.muscleBand];
    [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:workoutAtIndex.comment];
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowWorkoutDetails"]) {
        IFitDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.thisWorkout = [self.muscleBandDataController objectInMasterMuscleBandListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }        
}

@end
```

**Here DetailViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Workouts;

@interface IFitDetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Workouts *thisWorkout;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *muscleBandLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *exerciseLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *seriesLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nActionsInSerieLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *measureLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *weightLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *commentLabel;

@end
```

**and finally my DetailViewController.m:**

```
#import "IFitDetailViewController.h"

#import "Workouts.h"

@interface IFitDetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation IFitDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setWorkout:(Workouts *)newWorkout
{
    if (_thisWorkout != newWorkout) {
        _thisWorkout = newWorkout;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    Workouts *theWorkout = self.thisWorkout;
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    if (theWorkout) {

        self.muscleBandLabel.text = theWorkout.muscleBand;
        self.exerciseLabel.text = theWorkout.exercise;
        self.seriesLabel.text = theWorkout.series;
        self.nActionsInSerieLabel.text = theWorkout.nActionsInSerie;
        self.measureLabel.text = theWorkout.measure;
        self.weightLabel.text = theWorkout.weight;
        self.title = [formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)theWorkout.date];
        self.commentLabel.text = theWorkout.comment;        
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```